# evo-calendar, dots covering date Fix?

Tags: php, html, css, calendar

Is it possible with the evo calendar to limit the dots displaying by the dates to two or arrange them, so them so they does not cover the date.(div.type-bullet) And feel free to critic my code and help me improve. Thanks for your help - Simon
-[I mean this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cMA9.png)

P.S. most of the time i have around 15dots per day

```
<?php
// Include your database connection code here
include('db_connect.php');

// Retrieve events from your database
$sql = "SELECT id, name, start_date, end_date FROM booking";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$events = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Close the database connection
mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Evo Calendar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/evo-calendar@1.1.2/evo-calendar/css/evo-calendar.min.css">
    <style>
        .header {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        .header-link {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        .add-button {
            background-color: #4caf50;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <a href="/" class="header-link">Home</a>
        <button class="add-button" onclick="redirectToAddPage()">Add Event</button>
    </div>
    <div id="calendar"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/evo-calendar@1.1.2/evo-calendar/js/evo-calendar.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        // Function to redirect to the add page
        function redirectToAddPage() {
            window.location.href = "../dateSelect.php";
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Convert PHP events array to JavaScript events array
            var events = <?php echo json_encode($events); ?>;
            console.log(events); // Add this line to check if events array is populated correctly

            // Create an empty array to store the expanded events
            var expandedEvents = [];

            // Iterate through the events array
            events.forEach(function(event) {
                var startDate = new Date(event.start_date);
                var endDate = new Date(event.end_date);

                // Iterate through each day between the start_date and end_date
                for (var date = startDate; date <= endDate; date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)) {
                    // Create a new event object for each day
                    var expandedEvent = {
                        id: event.id,
                        name: event.name,
                        date: date.toISOString().split('T')[0], // Format the date as YYYY-MM-DD
                        description: '', // Add an empty description for now
                        color: '#ffcc80'
                    };

                    // Push the expanded event to the expandedEvents array
                    expandedEvents.push(expandedEvent);
                }
            });

            // Initialize the calendar with the expanded events
            $('#calendar').evoCalendar({
                calendarEvents: expandedEvents
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Limiting the amount of events you add per date (that's creating the dots, I assume?) would probably make rather little sense - likely to interfere with other(?) calendar functionality. Might be best to just hide them using CSS, using some sort of :nth-child and general sibling combinator rule.

Answer (score 0):

The dots on each page are multiple div elements within the parent span tag

```html
<span class="event-indicator">
    <div class="type-bullet"><div class="type-holiday">
</span>
```

In your script, create a function where you can

1. Get the active date of your calendar
2. Loop through all the visible days
3. Count the number of events on each day and assign them to the `.event-indicator` class (This replaces all the `div` elements with an integer
4. You can style the modified  anyway you want with css
5. Under `(document).ready` include your new function to update the view.

   - You can also use `fetch` to update the views each time you POST/PATCH/DELETE an event

An example function is

```js
// Function to update daily event count for visible days in calendar
function updateEventsView() {
    // Get the list of active events for the day of interest
    var currentActiveDate = $("#calendar").evoCalendar('getActiveDate');
    
    // Loop over all the visible calendar days that are accessed from a NodeList
    document.querySelectorAll('.calendar-day').forEach(function(dateDiv) {
        // Get the date string of each visible day div
        var dateString = dateDiv.querySelector(".day").getAttribute('data-date-val');
        // Make that day active and count the number of visible events
        $('#calendar').evoCalendar('selectDate', dateString);
        var allActiveEvents = $('#calendar').evoCalendar('getActiveEvents');

        // Syntax to check if the event-indicator span exists in the .calendar-day div
        var eventIndicator = dateDiv.querySelector('.event-indicator');

        // Change the value of the event-indicator span
        if (allActiveEvents.length > 0) {
            dateDiv.querySelector('.event-indicator').textContent = allActiveEvents.length;
        } else if (allActiveEvents.length === 0 && eventIndicator) {
            eventIndicator.remove();
        };
    });

    // After updating the list, change the active date back to what it was 
    $('#calendar').evoCalendar('selectDate', currentActiveDate);
};
```

[Evo-calendar view with daily event count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPVu9.png)